# client js to c# server socket connecting

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

We're trying to connect the web page to the server using WebSockets - please take a look and see if you can spot anything wrong, thank you in advance

c#

```
public static void Main()
        {
            
            
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("ws://127.0.0.1"), 9122);

                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server has started on  192.168.1.102.{0}Waiting for a connection...", Environment.NewLine);

                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");
            

        }
```

js

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9122", "protocolOne");

                    exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
                        exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
                        console.log(`gdsfgdsfg`);
                    }
```

Comment: Don't use 127.0.0.1 for both the server and client you will get an excetion.  Change the websocket to the IP address of the machine and/or make listener IPAddress.Any.

Comment: @jdweng any chance you could help us out in discord? we've done that but it seems like we're still in somewhat of a pickle

Comment: Try something like this.  You can use host name instead of IP :             TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9122);

            string LocalHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry LocalHostIPEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(LocalHostName);
            IPAddress LocalHostIP = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList[1]; //Zero is IPV6 and One is IPV4
            string ip = "ws://" + LocalHostIP.ToString() + ":9122";
            var exampleSocket = new WebSocket(ip, "protocolOne");

Comment: @jdweng thank you for the help - I really appreciate it. :) It's always great to be able to ask for professional help when you get stuck badly. c# has been causing nothing but problems for us though unfortunately, we've decided to go node js for backend since we're more familiar with it and it seems easier for us, again though - really appreciate everything. thank you.